# gb4e label appears under image when I reduce its size, I want it to be above

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree, gb4e

I've created a syntactic tree using TikZ, and it works well, also when placed inside an `{exe}` of `gb4e`, for example the following code:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex54} \Tree [.TP$_1$ [.DP$_1$ \edge[roof]; {John} ] [.T\1$_1$ 
[.T$_1$ ] [.VP$_1$  [.V$_1$ likes ][.DP$_2$ \edge[roof]; {Mary} ]]]]  
\end{exe}
```

It generates the following, just as I wish:
[image]

But sometimes, I have a tree that is too wide, so I'd like to make it smaller, and I run the following (note the addition of `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]` and the corresponding `\end{tikzpicture}`:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex54} \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]\Tree [.TP$_1$ [.DP$_1$ 
\edge[roof]; {John} ] [.T\1$_1$ [.T$_1$ ] [.VP$_1$  [.V$_1$ likes ][.DP$_2$ 
\edge[roof]; {Mary} ]]]]  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{exe}
```

Now, for some reason, the label appears at the *bottom* of the image:
[image]

How can I fix that?
(Another solution to make the tree less wide would also work).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always post compilable minimal code examples (MWE).

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the first image, just add `baseline` to the `tikzpicture` options.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=.9]


\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you want to have the number line up with the top of the tree, you need to do some manual adjustments:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-2ex]current bounding box.north)},scale=.9]


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex54}\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-2ex]current bounding box.north)},scale=.9]\Tree [.TP$_1$ [.DP$_1$ 
\edge[roof]; {John} ] [.T\1$_1$ [.T$_1$ ] [.VP$_1$  [.V$_1$ likes ][.DP$_2$ 
\edge[roof]; {Mary} ]]]]  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Great, this certainly helps. 
Thank you very much @alan-munn!